# how to create document set in library with one/some property(s)?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, jsom

I am trying to create document set in document library with one property but am unable to get it as 100%,here am able to create document set only ,property is not getting create,for this whole thing am using JSOM
my script code is as below.

```
function CreateDocumentSet() {
    var docSetName = "folder";
    var properties = {};
    properties['Remark'] = "this is Property";
    var docSetContentTypeID = "0x0120D520";
    var parentFolder = prep.get_rootFolder();
    ctx.load(web);
    ctx.load(prep);
    ctx.load(parentFolder);

    var docSetContentType = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
    ctx.load(docSetContentType);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(ctx, parentFolder, docSetName, docSetContentType.get_id());
        var docSetFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(parentFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '/' + docSetName);
        var docSetFolderItem = docSetFolder.get_listItemAllFields();
        if (properties != null) {
            for (var property in properties) {
                if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property) === true) {
                    docSetFolderItem.set_item(property, properties[property]);
                }
            }
        }
        docSetFolderItem.update();
        ctx.load(docSetFolderItem);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            success(docSetFolderItem);
        }, fail);
    },
    fail);

}
```

does any one have any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

In the code mentioned above, i didn't see the doc lib name,hence have added it in below code.

Can you try and check using below code:

```
function createDocumentSet() {

    var docLibraryName = 'Documents'; //change as per your doc lib name
    var docSetName = 'folder';
    var properties = {};
    properties['Remark'] = "this is Property";

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();

    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(docLibraryName);
    ctx.load(list);

    var parentFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
    ctx.load(parentFolder);
    var docSetContentTypeID = "0x0120D520";
    var docSetContentType = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
    ctx.load(docSetContentType);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(ctx, parentFolder, docSetName, docSetContentType.get_id());
        var docSetFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(parentFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '/' + docSetName);
        var docSetFolderItem = docSetFolder.get_listItemAllFields();
        if (properties != null) {
            for (var property in properties) {
                if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property) === true) {
                    docSetFolderItem.set_item(property, properties[property]);
                }
            }
        }
        docSetFolderItem.update();
        ctx.load(docSetFolderItem);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            console.log("success");
        }, function (a,b){
            console.log("error");
        });
    },function (a,b){
        console.log("error");
    });

}
```